# Applying Gaussian Process Regression recursively?

Tags: gaussian-process

I think if you start with a prior, and condition on one obs to get the posterior, then use that as the prior for the next point and then get the posterior adding the 2nd point and so on it should be the same as conditioning on all the points at once (basic Bayes rule).

But am looking for a write up of griding through this computationally. What is the kernel in the 2nd step where you have conditioned on one point? If this works, this must exist and be called something? Recursive GPR is something else in the literature. Are there any issues with this approach ... perhaps something I am thinking is non-sensical?

Comment: The Gaussian process is defined in terms of the kernel function that calculates distances between the current point and all the training data if you add more data, you just compute the result using more data and in this sense, it is updated.

Comment: Yes, there is some block structure you can re-use like that. It looks like kalman basically. Was just thinking through the calculation if you apply Bayes' rule. It must work out, just not obvious that it does.

Comment: In Kalman filter there is a state model additionally.  Gaussian process has a closed form solution from [Bayesian  interpretation of kernel regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_interpretation_of_kernel_regularization#Derivation_of_the_estimator).  Kernel functions appear in the covariance matrix between points known and unknown along time in block structure as prior, and posteriors are the solutions.

Comment: Btw, there was similar question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/570779/is-it-possible-to-update-a-gaussian-process-individually-for-each-observation does it answer yours?

Comment: @Tim Yes! that is the grinding through the calculation. THanks.

Comment: I marked it as a duplicate. Notice that this exactly the same as re-calculating everything using all the data, it just can be done step by step, as in Bayesian updating.